# file_put_contents stops my code from executing

Tags: php, server

I want to send some data as a GET request to my php page (`submit.php`) and save it in a local file. I have:

```
$loc = 'data.txt';
if(isset($_GET["data"])) {
    echo 'set';
    file_put_contents($loc, $_GET["data"], FILE_APPEND);
}
echo 'foo';
```

But when I access `submit.php?data=bar`, nothing happens to `data.txt`; moreover, `echo 'foo'` does not seem to execute. Why is this?

Comment: Do you see any error messages and do you have error_reporting und display_errors enabled?

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact code? It appears you have an extra closing parenthesis after `$_GET["data"]` that I would expect to prevent it from executing at all. One thing I would try is to add:
    `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', TRUE); ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);` at the top.

Comment: @Rangad I don't see any error messages, which is itself weird. And I'm not sure if I have those enabled; how do I check?

Comment: @ZJM I also thought that was it, but it turns out it was a typo when I was transferring my code to here (I had to simplify it). I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo 'foo'` does not execute because `file_put_contents()` encounters an error and the execution stop.

Put `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICES); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` in front of your script to let PHP display the errors on screen.

This way you can find that, I guess, the process that runs the PHP code (the web server probably) does not have the rights to write in the directory where you store the code.

Change `$loc` to `'/tmp/data.txt'` and it will work.
Or, even better, create a new directory, set its permissions to `rwx` for everybody and change the code to write files in it.

Comment: You got it, thanks! Turns out I was working in the wrong directory, and, as you said, it couldn't write there.